# Time vindicates those that are right and righteous, like me

Tags: discussion

I just wanted to share a story, my narrative on this network.

In Sep 27 '17, I asked a question about [how SQL Server implemented `GREATEST` and `LEAST`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/187090/2639). This question was largely rejected by the network. I most likely had to argue to keep it open. The problem, presumably, was because I mentioned how other databases implemented this functionality. This helps with the indexing. The question immediately acquired 8 downvotes.

Today it sits at +17, and has 26k views. That's a lot of appreciation. That's a lot of people that my contribution helped.

But how come it got 8 downvotes on first reception? That's a pretty heavy rejection. Why do we do this to people who ask questions? 99% of my downvotes come within a week of submission. Is it that the scrutiny is more well deserved in that frame? Or that the people that use the site most are incorrigible 'netizens' compared to the appreciative people that I serve, the people who come in desperation and leave enlightened without being established DBA.SE members.

I just wonder how many other stunning examples of brilliance and humanity leave simply because their skin is thinner, and they're less resilient.

Comment: Where is the question here? Are you really asking for opinions about why 7 people might have down-voted a specific and controversial "question" more than two years ago, before it was edited by others into something that some now find useful?

Comment: @AaronBertrand this is meta. if you're looking for questions check out [dba.se]

Comment: Meta is still a Q & A format, Evan. If you're looking to pontificate on your opinions and complaints, check out [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/).

Comment: It's a Q/A format. I thought out loud -- providing a prompt. And, now others have responded with their input. If you don't agree with this format, take it up with ♦♦Paul♦♦ who is at least trying to constructively participate. If you disagree, just think real hard and long about how you can change behavior and better the community in the form of a question to make yourself happy: we'll both be in the same boat.

Comment: I still can’t decipher what actual, answerable question you’ve asked here. Just because someone addresses some of your thought fragments doesn’t make it a question. Now, go ahead, get the last useless word, as you do.

Comment: I'll just go back to the first word, it was good enough "this is meta. if you're looking for questions check out Database Administrator." Not sure what you don't get. Whole network is a Q/A format. Meta requires no question -- you can provide thoughts, data, requests, etc. The site itself -- [dba.se] -- is strictly for questions.

Answer (score 12):

> I most likely had to argue to keep it open.

There was one 'recommend closure' (needs more focus) flag by a non-regular user of the site. The resulting [close review](https://dba.stackexchange.com/review/close/99661) was completed unanimously with three Leave Open votes. The first comment was left by Erik Darling:

> > Since you already know that it doesn't, perhaps a better question title would be "How do SQL Server users calculate LEAST and GREATEST?". Otherwise, it sounds like a feature request that would make a better Connect Item, assuming you can get the site to load within a few hours.

to which you replied:

> > @sp_BlitzErik updated, good point.

There were a few other comments, discussing the availability of a free version on Linux, and mentioning online sites where things can be tested. All very conversational and constructive.

> But how come it got 8 downvotes on first reception?

It didn't, it received 7 on Sep 27 '17. One more came along on Mar 6 '18.

As I recall, you were on a bit of an anti-SQL Server mission at the time, and this latest post seemed to rub people up the wrong way. To be blunt, it was the way you were conducting and presenting yourself at time that caused the negative reaction.

> Today it sits at +17, and has 26k views.

Yes, it is a useful Q & A (especially the answers, as is so often the case). If someone else had asked it, it would probably be scored higher and have fewer, if any, downvotes. As you must be aware, your reputation precedes you on much of the network, and you were relatively new to dba.se at the time.

> 99% of my downvotes come within a week of submission. Is it that the scrutiny is more well deserved in that frame?

That's pretty normal. The question was most visible at the start of its life, especially to people with the ability to downvote (125 rep). It also benefited from 11 edits, which probably improved it.

> I just wonder how many other stunning examples of brilliance and humanity leave simply because their skin is thinner, and they're less resilient.

Who would know? I will say that I doubt your very specific experiences will ever be duplicated. You are probably one of a kind, or at least a very small group.

Comment: "If someone else had asked it, it would probably be scored higher" so I'm a victim of people not having good tastes, and disliking me. "To be blunt, it was you" victim blaming is a violation of the CoC.

Comment: You're not a victim, it's self inflicted :)

Comment: I lolled at victim blaming. I very much doubt that you actually feel like a victim.

Comment: I am the Warrior King of Victims everywhere, and I shall not be blamed for people disliking me for it.

Comment: This post is pro-establishment propaganda. I hear Bloomberg is hiring, and if you accept you won't have to use SQL Server.

Comment: @EvanCarroll What else did you expect from The Establishment?

Answer (score 5):

Evan, you should do stand-up comedy with lines like "stunning examples of brilliance and humanity".

Perhaps you're seeing downvotes because your reputation precedes you?  FYI, I didn't downvote that question.  This one, yes, but not that one on main.

Comment: I should sue for plagiarism!

Comment: just what I was thinking lol.  Except your answer is far nice than mine was.

Answer (score 4):

> I just wonder how many other stunning examples of brilliance and humanity leave simply because their skin is thinner, and they're less resilient.

Personally, I've ventured into workplace, worldbuilding, sci-fi, politics and philosophy, but quickly deleted my profiles on those forums after encounters with their obnoxious moderators. I had several negative encoutners with that Monica lady.

DBA is one of the better forums - the people who mod it are recognized leaders in their fields. I've learned more from this forum than I did from college.

I think what you've encountered is that there is more than one school of thought on what the up and down buttons mean:

To the mods, it means 'does this follow the forum guidelines'. Most posts don't - hence the early downvotes.

To lurkers, it normally means 'did I find this useful'. Some posts that don't follow the guidelines are still useful.

On the more subjective forums, the arrows often mean 'do I agree with this' or 'did I find this entertaining'.

It's hard to ask a good question on DBA - the problems we encounter can be pretty complex, and by the time you can clearly and logically explain your problem, you're 3/4 to solving it.

Ontop of that, all of the beginner questions have already been asked, anwered - and show up in a duckduckgo search if you know what to type. It's actually hard to think of something that hasn't been asked yet, so most of the new questions are kind of bad, or could be anwered with a google search.