# Why would we ask questions if they are just going to get downvoted?

Tags: discussion

Title says it all. What the [REDACTED]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time vindicates those that are right and righteous, like me](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3317/time-vindicates-those-that-are-right-and-righteous-like-me)

Comment: @mustaccio rather ironic considering that meta question currently sits at -10 ;)
Or did you link because James has a (positively voted) answer there?

Answer (score 3):

I think a lot of information on the linked Q & A [Time vindicates those that are right and righteous, like me](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3317/time-vindicates-those-that-are-right-and-righteous-like-me) explains a lot.

In the end it isn't the moderators that down-vote questions and answers, but the community as a whole. Moderators only step in when the proverbial `[redacted]` hits the fan.

If your questions are getting down-voted then the community feels that the questions don't meet the site's expectations regarding quality, content, or wording.

Have a look at the [How to Ask](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [How not to Ask](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) sections of the Help Centre to get an idea what the community expects.

I had a choppy start when I started out here and the community is always evolving so questions that were once deemed unfit are suddenly considered ok two years down the road.

Try and find a balance on how to ask and if you think your questions have been wrongfully down-voted and closed, then ask for clarification in the comments or read up on [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions)

Good luck.